# Ctrl + Shift + N launches the default browser with the text on the clipboard as the url

Tags: windows-7, keyboard-shortcuts

I don't know, why this happens, but when I want to create a new folder (Win 7), I press Ctrl + Shift + N. It used to work before, but now, the shortcut seems to have been overridden. It launches the default browser with the text on the clipboard as the url. How do I fix this?

EDIT: Fixed it. I noticed that ClipX was assigning a hotkey.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

I had the exact same problem.  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> should create a new folder, but instead was opening a browser and pasting the clipboard.  I realized it was being used by ClipX for navigtation.  ClipX is a clipboard history application.  You can right-click the ClipX icon in the tray and choose Configure.  In the resulting window you can change that shortcut key association.

Comment: This fixed my and the OA's problem. It should be voted as the correct answer.

Comment: And the magic of internet happen. That was it for me, thank you, drove me mad ^^

Answer (score 7):

Use [ActiveHotkeys](http://www.donationcoder.com/Forums/bb/index.php?topic=18189.0) application , which will show you the current active hotkeys.

Answer (score 1):

Check to ensure you don't have any software installed that may be overriding the hotkey, such as AutoHotkey.